# Trouble Initializing TimeZone from TimeZone.abbreviation()

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nstimezone

I am storing user birth dates on my backend via storing a date component dictionary. It looks something like this:

```
{
    "day": 1,
    "month": 1,
    "year": 1970,
    "timeZone": "GMT"
}
```

To store this object, it grabs the user's birth day, month, and year from user input. The user time zone, however, is gathered via `TimeZone.current.abbreviation()`.

Now, some of my user birthdate objects on my backend have their `"timeZone"` formatted as `"CST"`, `"BST"`, or `"PDT"`. `"timeZone"`s that are formatted this way successfully initialize a `TimeZone` on the front end via `let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")!`, `let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "BST")!`, or `let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PDT")!`, respectively.

The problem is, other user birthdate objects on my backend have their `"timeZone"` formatted as `"GMT+8"`. When trying to initialize `"timeZone"`s formatted like this via `let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+8")!`, the initialization returns `nil`. I also tried `let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT+8")!`, but this returns `nil` as well.

Is there a way to initialize a `TimeZone` when it is formatted with respect to its offset to GMT as opposed to its unique abbreviation? I've seen a `TimeZone` initializer that is `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: Int)`. Could I simply take the `8` from `"GMT+8"` and multiply it by `3600` (the number of seconds in an hour) and pass this result to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: Int)`?

Comment: Avoid using timezone abbreviations. They are not unique and not every timezone has a useful abbreviation. Use timezone identifiers or offsets.

Comment: To expand on rmaddy's comment - "CST" might be "Central Standard Time" or it might be "China Standard Time" or "Cuba Standard Time".   "BST" might be "British Summer Time", or it might be "Bangladesh Standard Time" or "Bougainville Standard TIme".

Comment: So basically, I need to write some conversion code for existing users that updates their user object to reference their `TimeZone`'s identifier rather than abbreviation. What is the benefit of Apple letting `TimeZone` initialize from the abbreviation if it is so ambiguous. For example, if I pass `TimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")!`, will that initialize China Standard Time's time zone or Cuba Standard Time's?

Comment: If you are storing the birthday as date components (year, month, day) do you really need to store time zone? Within the meaning of a “birthday”, surely the time zone is only relevant on-device? Or are you doing some backend stuff based on the birthdays?

Comment: It appears Apple has their abbreviations initialize to only one `TimeZone`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892290/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-abbreviations-for-timezonewithabbreviation . So long as its consistent, it doesn't matter what information the abbreviation is communicating, as the components (including timeZone) are being used to calculate the user's age and communicate this to other users. For the edge cases of "GMT+8" I may try to calculate the timeZone's offset and initialize their TimeZone this way. This is easier than writing conversion code.

Comment: @Chris the app is similar to Tinder in that you can make a user profile and match with people within a certain radius of you. The TimeZone is used to calculate the user's current age. It is pretty nitpicky, but you could be within a 50 mile radius of somebody and be in a different timezone than they are. If I ignore TimeZones, it could appear to another user that a user is only 22, when in reality they've been 23 for about 30 minutes, and the viewing user's timeZone hasn't transitioned into the next day yet.

Comment: @DavidChopin Cool. Nothing wrong with being precise! :)

Comment: @DavidChopin Could you store the `TimeZone.identifier` property. You can get a list of all possible ones with the static property `knownTimeZoneIdentifiers`. They’re different from the abbreviations.

Comment: @Chris well, this app is in beta currently and is in some users hands. I could either write conversion code, or write code that adapts to this fringe case to be released in the next update. While you guys are all correct that when doing something similar in the future, I should and will use `TimeZone.identifier`. For the time being, I am finding it possible to split `"GMT+3:30"` into `"+"`, `"3"` hours,  and `"30"` minutes. This tells me that I can initialize the correct `TimeZone` via `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: (3*3600) + (30*60))`. I should be able to do this consistently.

Comment: @Chris I seem to have gotten it to work, I could post my solution without having to write conversion code if you'd like to see it. Its kinda hacky, but it is seeming to work.

Comment: @DavidChopin Sounds good. Glad you got sorted.

Comment: @DavidChopin Yep it would be good to post an answer that worked if it’s not too much hassle - may help someone else in a similar situation.

Comment: I went ahead and posted something in case it helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing code that adapts my application to account for these unexpected fringe cases where a TimeZone's abbreviation is formatted like `"GMT+8"` rather than `"SGT"`. I created an extension to `TimeZone`:

```swift
extension TimeZone {
    static func timeZone(from string: String) -> TimeZone {
        //The string format passed into this function should always be similar to "GMT+8" or "GMT-3:30"

        if string.contains("±") {
            //This case should always be "GMT±00:00", or simply GMT
            return TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
        } else {

            //If the string doesn't contain "±", then there should be some offset. We will split the string into timeZone components. "GMT+8" would split into ["GMT", "8"]. "GMT-3:30" would split int ["GMT","3","30"]
            let timeZoneComponents = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-:"))
            var isAheadOfGMT: Bool!

            //Check if the string contains "+". This will dictate if we add or subtract seconds from GMT
            if string.contains("+") {
                isAheadOfGMT = true
            } else {
                isAheadOfGMT = false
            }

            //Grab the second element in timeZoneElements. This represents the offset in hours
            let offsetInHours = Int(timeZoneComponents[1])!

            //Convert these hours into seconds
            var offsetInSeconds: Int!
            if isAheadOfGMT {
                offsetInSeconds = offsetInHours * 3600
            } else {
                offsetInSeconds = offsetInHours * -3600
            }

            //Check if there is a colon in the passed string. If it does, then there are additional minutes we need to account for
            if string.contains(":") {
                let additionalMinutes = Int(timeZoneComponents[2])!
                let additionalSeconds = additionalMinutes * 60
                offsetInSeconds += additionalSeconds
            }

            //Create a TimeZone from this calculated offset in seconds
            let timeZoneFromOffset = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: offsetInSeconds)!

            //Return this value
            return timeZoneFromOffset
        }
    }
}
```

It is used like so:

```swift
let json: [String:String] = ["timeZone":"GMT+8"]
let timeZone = json["timeZone"]
let birthDate: BirthDate!
if let timeZoneFromAbbrev = TimeZone(abbreviation: timeZone) {
    birthDate = BirthDate(day: birthDay, month: birthMonth, year: birthYear, timeZone: timeZoneFromAbbrev)
} else {       
    let timeZoneFromOffset = TimeZone.timeZone(from: timeZone)
    print(timeZoneFromOffset.abbreviation())
    //Prints "GMT+8"

    birthDate = BirthDate(day: birthDay, month: birthMonth, year: birthYear, timeZone: timeZoneFromOffset)
}
```

My `BirthDate` class for context:

```swift
class BirthDate {
    var day: Int
    var month: Int
    var year: Int
    var timeZone: TimeZone

    init(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int, timeZone: TimeZone) {
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.timeZone = timeZone
    }
}
```

Time zones are funny things to work with. If anybody sees issue with the `TimeZone` extension above, please let me know. I think I've accounted for all scenarios, but could be mistaken.

Comment: Good work man. Save alot of hastle.